# ClassNotFoundException when initializing Apache Camel atmosphere-websocket endpoint

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, atmosphere

Running Camel 2.17.3 on Karaf 4.0.5 with camel-atmosphere-websocket feature Atmosphere (v2.4.3) raises the following exception:

```
Cannot load the WebSocketProtocol org.apache.camel.component.atmosphere.websocket.WebsocketHandler                  
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.component.atmosphere.websocket.WebsocketHandler not found by org.atmosphere.runtime [203] 
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1574)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:805)[:1.8.0-internal]
at org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils.loadClass(IOUtils.java:370)[203:org.atmosphere.runtime:2.4.3]
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.initWebSocket(AtmosphereFramework.java:1762)[203:org.atmosphere.runtime:2.4.3]
```

The package is exported by the bundle org.apache.camel.camel-atmosphere-websocket.

Am I missing any dependencies or is there an issue with the startup order?

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-atmosphere-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
    <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

As mentioned you need to use the same version for all dependecies.
Reference : http://camel.apache.org/atmosphere-websocket.html
Hope this Works.